# Why would M# be harder to Google than C#?

Tags: search-engine, google-search

I read just now in a comment on another question titled [Effective Googling for short names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930488/effective-googling-for-short-names)

> C# isn't bad to Google for at all. It would be a *lot* harder if it were called M#, by the way.

Why?  What am I missing?

Comment: Well, once the # is removed, you have to compete with the Metre page on wikipedia and a whole host of other things... not a good thing for a programming language to compete with :)

Comment: @workmad3 - but if you include Metre for M, you'd have to include (for C) Celcius/Centigrade - not to mention Carbon and the speed of light.

Answer (score 9):

It turns out I was somewhat wrong. I had *thought* that C# just happened to benefit from an understanding of musical keys - a search for "G#" finds plenty of results about the musical key of G#. (This is shown by experimentation, by the way - despite working at Google I don't know anything about the search engine. At least, not on this front.)

However, in this case not only does C# benefit from the musical key side of things, but Google's own help pages explain that [C# and other programming languages are special-cased](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?answer=136861#exceptions_punctuations):

> **Punctuation that is not ignored**
>
> - Punctuation in popular terms that have
>     particular meanings, like [ C++ ] or [
>     C# ] (both are names of programming
>     languages), are not ignored.
> - The
>     dollar sign ($) is used to indicate
>     prices. [ nikon 400 ] and [ nikon $400
>     ] will give different results.
> - The
>     hyphen - is sometimes used as a signal
>     that the two words around it are very
>     strongly connected. (Unless there is
>     no space after the - and a space
>     before it, in which case it is a
>     negative sign.)
> - The underscore symbol
>     _ is not ignored when it connects two words, e.g. [ quick_sort ].

It would be interesting to know how long it would take a theoretical language "M#" to become searchable... but I'm not going to start speculating on that in a public forum :)

(Note that the Spec# home page comes up as the *second* link when you [search Google for Spec#](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=spec%23). At least it's there and pretty prominent though.)

Comment: I just *love* that Wierd Al comes up as a first-page result on M# ;-p

Comment: When one type of punctuation is accepted, that probably helps other following the same pattern, like F#. Searching for i++ actually does find question about incrementing the i variable, but searching for ++i does not...

Answer (score 1):

I'll put up my opinion extrapolated from my comment.

As others have suggested, special chars are ignored by Google. But C# may have had a head start in not being ignored (or at least turned into "C") because of the musical note C# which was probably allowed for searches like "Some piece of music in C#". M# would not have benefited such.

Comment: Yes, A# through G# all seem to work as searches without having the symbol removed. Even though B# is C and E# is F!