# How do I search Google for code and other programming related keywords? It seems to strip special characters

Tags: search, character

One of the problems I have with Google is that it seems to strip special characters like dots, commas and some other special characters, which are usually what I'm looking for when I'm trying to find anything programming-related

ex: **`django @ sign`** returns irrelevant data. Perhaps you know a way (or an alternative/technique) to make this possible?

> #### Related Questions
>
> - [Effective Googling for short names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930488/effective-googling-for-short-names)
> - [Why would M# be harder to Google than C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932915/why-would-m-be-harder-to-google-than-c/932948#932948)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried http://www.google.com/codesearch?

Comment: Bingo! that's what im looking for.

Comment: "The requested URL /codesearch was not found on this server."

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for actual code examples, you can try code.google.com. Otherwise, the safest bet is to find the main website for whatever language you've got questions about and look around there, although a little digging is likely to turn it up on google.

Comment: After looking at code.google.com, this is still not what i'm looking for.